# Edmx add entity(table) by code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

How can I create a new table in my EDMX file in Visual Studio by code?
I want to create a new table copying the properties from a DBML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunate in code it's unreal, and also you needn't it. Because edmx model it's graphic. There are a lot of references in properties, and other unnecessary. You have to add table by hand. Below I left link and phto, how you can you add table to edmx model
[image]

And also left video it's very helpful
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx
or I have misunderstood you